# Scons for C# setup question

Tags: c#, build, scons

I use Scons from time to time, and I see it's a good tool for building simple C# project.
I guess there should be some modification of Scons for using C#.

Can I get some help on how to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can start with the [SCONS C# builder](http://www.scons.org/wiki/CsharpBuilder) wiki page, and work through issues with people on the [SCONS mailing lists](http://www.scons.org/lists.php).  Some [people have already done some work](http://scons.tigris.org/ds/viewMessage.do?dsForumId=1272&dsMessageId=2434181) in this area, but it seems it may have fallen off and/or been some time ago.

I would guess that working through things there - and especially looking at what was already done - would be much more fruitful than a single question here, as the vast majority of mainstream c# users use msbuild, nant, psake, or another .net specific tool-chain.